# Automatic Printers Creation in Windows 7 based on a Text File

Tags: windows, printing, batch-file

I would like to create a simple batch file (...or vbs or Wscript) to install network printers on Computers running Windows 7.

I will get a TEXT FILE with this information Inside:

```
--------------------------------------> infoprint.txt

REM [COMPUTER_NAME] [PRINTER_NAME] [IP_ADDRESS]

PC00001 HP_4750 10.0.0.109
PC00001 HP_4650 10.0.0.110
PC00002 HP_4650 10.0.0.110
PC00003 HP_5000 10.0.0.111
PC00004 HP_4750 10.0.0.109
PC00004 HP_4650 10.0.0.110
PC00004 HP_8050 10.0.0.112
REM (and more...)
--------------------------------------
```

How can I make this script for reading the text file (infoprint.txt) that contain all the information needed for Printer Creation Under Windows 7 ?

The easy way is that every printers are HP and using the same Universal Print driver already installed on each Computer, so it will be easy to install the printers.

---

Comment: Look at the ready made vbscripts that windows gives you for printer stuff `C:\Windows\system32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US`